# Setting up Mixer Help

Tags: audio, mixer

I need some help setting up my mixer. It is a Radioshack 4 Channel Mixer with effects.  I have a speaker set, and the main speaker (Right) has input and output jacks (3.5mm)
My monitor also has input and output jacks (3.5mm).  My computer has rear input and output jacks (3.5mm, I'm not sure if they work, I don't know how to test them).
And it has front input and output jacks (3.5mm, not sure if the input works, don't know how to test it.)  **My monitor is hooked up to my computer via HDMI, so the sound goes to my monitor.**
Anyways, let me tell you how my mixer is setup.

1. My mixer has a USB port, so I have a USB cable going from my Mixer into my Computer (Although, I cannot tell if it is an input or output cable)
2. Then, I have an RCA to 3.5mm converting cable hooked into my mixer (RCAs are in the mixer) In the **Booth** output (The only output choices I have are Amp, Booth, and Record) then the 3.5mm end in my **Speakers** (Problem could be here)
3. My speakers are hooked up into my Monitor Output (Which, once again, is connected to my computer via HDMI, which sends the sound to the computer).
4. And lastly, I have my headphones hooked up into my speaker.

The Mixer partially works, Only the volume controls work.  Does anyone know what's going on? What am I doing wrong?
Also, I have virtual DJ pro downloaded, I just don't know what configurations to have.

Answer (score 3):

I would highly recommend reading the [manual](http://www.radioshack.com/graphics/uc/rsk/Support/ProductManuals/3200026_PM_EN.pdf) provided for your mixer. Page 8 has an explanation of the different outputs provided:

> - Amp: Connect the mixer’s output to your receiver or amplifier.
> - Booth: Connect to another receiver or amplifier, or connect to powered speakers.
> - Rec: Connect to the line input of your recording device so you can record sound from the  mixer.

Basically, these outputs are **all the same**. The names provided for them are essentially just labels.

The USB port is for **input** as well as **output**. The manual is ambiguous on its usage. To use it for input, it says to "Set the channel selector to USB." To record, it doesn't specify that you have to change any settings on the mixer.

If you are using the USB port for output, don't use the "booth" output into your monitor, it is redundant. Your mixer is already sending the audio through the USB cable.

Your problem is most likely that in Virtual DJ you have not selected your mixer's USB plug from the "input" menu.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there should be an option selector switch for channel 7 to accept usb audio from the computer. I would suggest you connect your speakers to the mixer output and take in audio from your pc. Whether you need to set your playback devices (enable mixer output) in audio properties depends on whether you had to install a driver for the mixer usb port to work.